# Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ibaction, nsindexpath

I have a `IBAction` which opens the UIActivityViewController:

```
@IBAction func share(sender: UIButton) {

    let defaultText = "Check out my Pinpoint: " + self.pinpoints[indexPath.row].main + ". Get Pinpoint on the iOS App Store!"
        if let imageToShare = UIImage(data: self.pinpoints[indexPath.row].image) {
            let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [defaultText, imageToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
            self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The error comes in the 2nd and 3rd line (starting with `let defaultText` and `if let imageToShare`.) It says:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'

The word `pinpoints` is an array storing main (UILabel) and image (UIImageView.)

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: `indexPath` isn't defined in your `IBAction`.  Did you mean to put this code in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @JAL So should I put this this `IBAction` method into the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: What do you want your application to do?  If you want this code to fire when a user taps on a cell, but it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  If not, you need to save the index of the item you want to share somewhere and use it in your IBAction.

Comment: @JAL What I want it to do is when I press the button, the `UIActivityViewController` appears. How do I save the index? You can put it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  How you you want the user to chose which pinpoint in your array is shared?

Comment: @JAL In each cell, there is a button - so, a button in every cell. When the user selects this button, the `UIActivityViewController` appears. In the `UIActivityViewController`, there is a default text (the `main` in the cell of which they selected via the button) and an image (the `image` in the cell of which they selected via the button.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your button a tag in cellforRowAtIndexPath which will be equal to indexPath.row

```
someButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Now your func should be:

```
IBAction func share(sender: UIButton) { 
    let defaultText = "Check out my Pinpoint: " + self.pinpoints[sender.tag].main + ". Get Pinpoint on the iOS App Store!" 
    if let imageToShare = UIImage(data: self.pinpoints[sender.tag].image) { 
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [defaultText, imageToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
         self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that there is no variable `indexPath` in the current scope. (You have neither a local variable nor an instance variable with that name)

What `NSIndexPath` do you expect to be using in the above code?

Do you have a table view or collection view that's active and you're trying to act on the current selection?

The way you need to resolve the issue is to point to an existing variable. (Presumably an instance variable.)

We can't tell you what that would be unless you provide more information.

What control is that IBAction connected to?

### EDIT:

If you have a share button and you want it to share the selected item in a table view then you should probably call the table view's `indexPathForSelectedRow` method to ask it for the selected cell.

Comment: `IBAction` is a method in a table view controller, that, when you press the button, it comes up with the UIActivityViewController (which when you press a way of sharing, there is a default text and the image.)

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: When you press WHAT button?

Comment: There is a button in the `Main.storyboard`, which I want this action to connect to.

Comment: In each cell, there is a button - so, a button in every cell. When the user selects this button, the UIActivityViewController appears. In the UIActivityViewController, there is a default text (the main in the cell of which they selected via the button) and an image (the image in the cell of which they selected via the button.)